# Error installing matplotlib

Tags: software-installation, python, 15.04, python-2.7, pip

I got the following error while trying to install `matplotlib` using `pip` under Ubuntu 15.04 (Python 2.7.9).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 304, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hP0laO/matplotlib
```

To be honest, I have no idea why the call to `setup.py`  failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using matplotlib and other [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) packages like *ipython* and *numpy* In Ubuntu 15.04. I've them installed from the Ubuntu repositories. May be you should install *python-matplotlib* with *apt-get*

Have you tried to run:
`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`

Comment: That fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to install `setuptools` if you haven't already. To do this download [ez_setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) file, navigate to the downloaded folder and execute:

```
python ez_setup.py
```

or as mentioned in pypi [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), you can also use the following command that will download the appropriate version and install it for you

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

Comment: `setuptools` was already installed. A re-install (just to be sure) had no effect.